# Swift - Adding Tie and playagain Function in Tic Tac Toe

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add tie function and after that play again button will appear.
I am new in Swift.

I am stuck in tie function and remaining it's working fine.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var winnerLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var playAgainButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func playAgain(_ sender: Any) {
        activeGame = true
        activePlayer = 1
        gameState = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

        var _: UIButton

        for i in 1..<10 {
            if let button = view.viewWithTag(i) as? UIButton {
                button.setImage(nil, for: [])
            }

            winnerLable.isHidden = true
            playAgainButton.isHidden = true

            winnerLable.center = CGPoint(x: winnerLable.center.x - 500, y: winnerLable.center.y)

            playAgainButton.center = CGPoint(x: playAgainButton.center.x - 500, y: playAgainButton.center.y)
        }
    }

    // 1 is nought and 2 is cross
    var turnCount = 0
    var activeGame = true
    var activePlayer = 1

    var gameState = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  //0 is empty

    var winnerCombination = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let activePosition = sender.tag - 1

        if gameState[activePosition] == 0  && activeGame {
            gameState[activePosition] = activePlayer

            if activePlayer == 1 {
                sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "nought.png"), for: [])
                activePlayer = 2
            } else {
                sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: [])
                activePlayer = 1
            }

            for combination in winnerCombination {
                if gameState[combination[0]] != 0 && gameState[combination[0]] == gameState[combination[1]] && gameState[combination[1]] == gameState[combination[2]]  {
                    // we have a winner
                    activeGame = false
                    winnerLable.isHidden = false
                    playAgainButton.isHidden = false

                    if gameState[combination[0]] == 1{
                        winnerLable.text = "Nought has won"
                    } else {
                        winnerLable.text = "crosses has won"
                    }
                }

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                    self.winnerLable.center = CGPoint(x: self.winnerLable.center.x + 500, y: self.winnerLable.center.y)

                    self.playAgainButton.center = CGPoint(x: self.playAgainButton.center.x + 500, y: self.playAgainButton.center.y)
                })
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        winnerLable.isHidden = true
        playAgainButton.isHidden = true

        winnerLable.center = CGPoint(x: winnerLable.center.x - 500, y: winnerLable.center.y)

        playAgainButton.center = CGPoint(x: playAgainButton.center.x - 500, y: playAgainButton.center.y)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add, at the end of the buttonPressed method, a test for tie:

```
else if !gameState.contains(0) {
    winnerLable.text = "it's a tie"
    winnerLable.isHidden = false
    playAgainButton.isHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. Normally I'd mark this sort of "tell me how to implement my app" question for closing as not a good fit, but you're new, so I'll answer it anyway.

You have logic in your `buttonPressed` IBAction to detect a winning state.

Thinking it through, what is a tie? A tie happens when every square is filled and there's no winner, right? So add an else clause of your "we have a winner" if statement, and loop through the whole array, looking for zero cells. If there is no winner, and there are no zero cells, it's a tie.

See if you can implement that logic. If not, edit your question to show the new code at the bottom, tell us what it does wrong, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: ohh its my mistake next time this will not happen for sure..

Comment: hello Duncan, I am not able do it pls give me some sample code for that so I can see that and implement in my code.pls help me for this

Comment: No, I won't give you "sample code." Simply create a function boardIsFull that returns a Bool. Have it loop through the game array and if any cell is zero, return false, else return TRUE if every entry in the array is non-zero. After each move, if you don't detect a winner, check for boardIsFull() == true. If it **is** true, you have a tie, else keep playing.

Comment: thanks Duncan its done....yeahhhh

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for get if  its a tie .... just put this code in main controller and you done...

activeGame = false

```
            for i in gameState {


                if i == 0 {

                    activeGame = true
                    break



                }
            }

            if activeGame  == false {

                winnerLable.text = "its a tie"
                winnerLable.isHidden = false
                playAgainButton.isHidden = false


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, here is my full working code...

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var winnerLable: UILabel!


@IBOutlet var playAgainButton: UIButton!



@IBAction func playAgain(_ sender: Any) {

    activeGame = true

    activePlayer = 1

    gameState = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    var _: UIButton

    for i in 1..<10 {

        if let button = view.viewWithTag(i) as? UIButton {

        button.setImage(nil, for: [])


        }

        winnerLable.isHidden = true

        playAgainButton.isHidden = true

        winnerLable.center = CGPoint(x: winnerLable.center.x - 500, y: winnerLable.center.y)

        playAgainButton.center = CGPoint(x: playAgainButton.center.x - 500, y: playAgainButton.center.y)



    }



}
 // 1 is nought and 2 is cross

var activeGame = true

var activePlayer = 1

var gameState = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  //0 is empty

var winnerCombination = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]


@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let activePosition = sender.tag - 1

    if gameState[activePosition] == 0  && activeGame {

        gameState[activePosition] = activePlayer


        if activePlayer == 1 {

            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "nought.png"), for: [])
            activePlayer = 2

        } else {

            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: [])
            activePlayer = 1
            }

        for combination in winnerCombination {


            if gameState[combination[0]] != 0 && gameState[combination[0]] == gameState[combination[1]] && gameState[combination[1]] == gameState[combination[2]]  {

            // we have a winner


                activeGame = false


                winnerLable.isHidden = false
                playAgainButton.isHidden = false

                if gameState[combination[0]] == 1{

                 winnerLable.text = "Nought has won"
                    break

                } else {

                winnerLable.text = "crosses has won"
                    break

                }

                }


            activeGame = false

            for i in gameState {


                if i == 0 {

                    activeGame = true
                    break



                }
            }

            if activeGame  == false {

               winnerLable.text = "its a tie"
               winnerLable.isHidden = false
                playAgainButton.isHidden = false


            }

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {

                self.winnerLable.center = CGPoint(x: self.winnerLable.center.x + 500, y: self.winnerLable.center.y)

                self.playAgainButton.center = CGPoint(x: self.playAgainButton.center.x + 500, y: self.playAgainButton.center.y)

               })

            }

        }

   }
    override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    winnerLable.isHidden = true

    playAgainButton.isHidden = true

    winnerLable.center = CGPoint(x: winnerLable.center.x - 500, y: winnerLable.center.y)

    playAgainButton.center = CGPoint(x: playAgainButton.center.x - 500, y: playAgainButton.center.y)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}